# Select current option in select menu

Tags: php, sql

Lets say `$cat` is 5, I want it to have the forum with ID 5 selected but it wont. I have a forum with ID 5. Shouldn't this work?

```
<select name="category" id="category">
foreach($db->query("SELECT name FROM forums ORDER BY disp_position ASC") as $row) {
   if ($cat == $row['id']) {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'" selected>'.$row['name'].'</option>';
   } else {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
   }
}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add **id field** in your select.

```
SELECT id, name FROM forums ORDER BY disp_position ASC
```

Comment: Wow im ashamed how could I not see that. I will accept your answer in 10 minutes.